# Sie waren mit die Ersten im Raum

Tags: meaning

Ich hab gerade in »Der nasse Fisch« von Volker Kutsche die folgende Passage gelesen:

- > Bruno parkte im Lichthof und sie [Bruno und Gereon, der Hauptcharakter des Romans] gingen zusammen in den kleinen Konferenzsaal.  Böhm hatte um acht eine Lagebesprechung im Fall Jänicke angesetzt.  **Sie waren mit die Ersten im Raum**, der sich langsam füllte.

Zuerst war ich ganz verblüfft von diesem *mit die Ersten*. Ich ahne jetzt, dass es um die Verbphrase *mit sein* handelt.

Soll der Satz heißen, dass sie als Erste in den leeren Raum eingetreten sind?  Waren vielleicht andere Leute schon da im Raum? Was wäre die Bedeutungsnuance zwischen:

- Sie waren die Ersten im Raum, der sich langsam füllte.
- Sie waren mit die Ersten im Raum, der sich langsam füllte.

Comment: Es gibt ein Verb `mitsein`?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler. Ich hab es in der Frage korrigiert.  Stimmt es besser jetzt?

Comment: Sie waren unter den Ersten, d.h. mehrere Menschen haben mehr oder weniger gleichzeitig und miteinander den Raum betreten. Diese Gruppe waren die Ersten, und zu diesen Ersten gehören auch Bruno und Gereon. So erklärt sich auch das "mit": Sie waren nicht alleinig die Ersten, sondern eben mit die Ersten. Sie teilen sich den ersten Platz mit anderen.

Comment: Im Duktus einiger Dialekte könnte das auch genau das heißen was da steht, "they were [together] with the first ones in the room", aber die Nominativ-Lesung "Sie waren _ die" ist wahrscheinlich gängiger, selbst dort wo "together with" den Nominativ regiert, *mit die Oma gehen*, anstelle des üblichen *mit der Oma gehen*, welches darüber hinaus of *mit der Oma mit gehen* lautet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Es handelt sich um das Adverb *mit* ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mit#2), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mit_neben_damit)). Die Bedeutung ist *auch* oder *neben X*. Als Adverb steht es mit beliebigen Verben, auch trennbaren (Partikelverben) und Präfixverben.

> *(zwei Leute versuchen ein Sofa die Treppe hochzutragen und schaffen es nicht*)
> Kannst du bitte mal **mit anfassen**?
>
> In unseren Kursen wird ihr Trainingsniveau  **mit berücksichtigt**. *(=neben
> anderen Faktoren)*

Das Ausgangsbeispiel ist eine Konstruktion von *mit* plus Superlativ, die in beiden obengenannten Wörterbüchern als *umgangssprachlich* charakterisiert wird.

> Er ist **mit der beste Spieler**, den wir haben.
> ~Er ist **einer der besten Spieler**, die wir haben.
>
> Heilbronn ist **mit die häßlichste Stadt**, die ich je gesehen habe.
> ~Heilbronn  ist **eine der häßlichsten Städte**, die ich je gesehen habe.
>
> Und da es sich bei Ihrem Heiratsantrag um **mit die wichtigste Frage im Leben** handelt, sollten Sie diese Frage auch mit der nötigen Ernsthaftigkeit und Glaubwürdigkeit vorbringen. ([Quelle](https://www.verlobungsring.de/magazin/der-perfekte-heiratsantrag/))
> ~um **eine der wichtigsten Fragen**
>
> Wir waren **mit die Ersten**, die ankamen.
> ~Wir waren **unter den Ersten**, die ankamen.

Neben den Umschreibungen mit *ein-* plus Genitiv und *unter* gibt es noch *gehören zu*.

> Heilbronn **gehört zu den häßlichsten Städten**, die ich je gesehen habe.
> Wir **gehörten zu den Ersten**, die ankamen.

Answer (score 11):

> Sie waren die Ersten im Raum.

Sie gingen in einen leeren Raum.

> Sie waren **mit** die Ersten im Raum.

Sie gingen in einen Raum, in dem schon einige wenige Leute waren.

Dieses *mit* ist keine Präposition, aber auch kein abgetrenntes Prefix, denn dieses würde z.B. im Partizip II ja wieder angeklebt. Das ist hier aber nicht der Fall.

> Sie sind **mit** die Ersten im Raum gewesen.

Es handelt sich also um eine Verbphrase *mit sein*, nicht um ein trennbares Verb *mitsein*.

---

EDIT: Aus dem Kommentar von Jonathan Scholbach:

> Sie waren mit die Ersten im Raum.

ist zudem synonym zu

> Sie waren unter den Ersten im Raum.

Man kann das sogar verallgemeinern:

> Es ist mit das Wichtigste.

ist synonym zu

> Es ist unter den wichtigsten Dingen.

Comment: "Sie gingen in einen Raum, in dem schon einige wenige Leute waren." ist keine akkurate Umschreibung. "Sie waren mit die Ersten" heißt, dass sie unter den Ersten waren, aber nicht die einzigen.

Comment: @RHa: Das hängt ein wenig von der als im Kontext ausreichend präzise empfundenen Sampling-Rate ab: Prüft man beispielsweise alle 10 Minuten den Füllungsgrads eines Raums und erblickt dabei zum ersten Mal Personen, so ist es durchaus korrekt, über jede dieser Personen zu sagen, sie sei "mit die erste Person" im fraglichen Raum gewesen. Realistisch gesehen können sich beim Moment des Eintetens einer gegebenen Person also schon mehrere der anderen Personen im Raum befunden haben (und ohne bewusste zeitliche Abstimmung wird dies außer beim allerersten Eintretenden auch fast immer der Fall ...

Comment: ... gewesen sein).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper das ist relativ unerheblich, wenn man ununterbrochen fünf Leute in den Raum gehen sieht und für die Aussage vollkommen egal ist, wer als allererster die Linie überschritt; Gegebenfalls gibt es gar keine Linie sondern nur einen Bezugspunkt, etwa *am Unfallort*. Man kann also meinen, es hinge mit ab von der gewünschten Präzision, wenn man auch einfach *Sie waren die ersten* sagen könnte, welches doch etwas unlogisch erscheint und Jankas Interpretation fördert, *Sie waren bei, dichte dran an, folgten dem allerallerersten*. Vgl. auch *Sie kamen mit den Ersten [dem ersten Schwung]*.